# text box clear issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, authentication

Ok im having a problem with the text boxes of my page holding values of the login info when i navigate to the start up page via the back button of the browser. i need the text boxes to clear when the page is loaded but when i use the code im using the text boxes stay equal to "" instead of the user input when the login button is clicked. heres my code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            txtEmailLog.Text = "";
            txtPasswordLog.Text = "";
        }
    }



    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerModel plyrModel = new PlayerModel();
        PlayerBLO plyrBLO = new PlayerBLO();

        List<PlayerModel> models = plyrBLO.GetAllPlayers();            

         foreach (PlayerModel player in models)
        {
            if (txtEmailLog.Text == player.PlayerEmail && txtPasswordLog.Text == player.PlayerPassword)
            {

                Session.Add("Player", player);

                Response.Redirect("PlayerMenu.aspx");

            }

            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Login! Retry or Register.";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When ever your page is loaded the following script will run.Include script file **jquery-1.4.1.js** in your LogIn form it will work even when you click Browser Back Button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // clear the text box values onload.
        $('#<%=txtEmailLog.ClientID%>').val('');
        $('#<%=txtPasswordLog.ClientID%>').val('')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: still the same problem when i get to the origianl page where i executed to login my login info is still in the text box.

Comment: check the script **jquery-1.4.1.js** file is loaded or not. And also see the path for that is correct or not in my example i kept **Scripts**, you just check your end.I test its working fine for me

Answer (score -1):

there are other ways, this is one of them

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // rest of your code
      txtEmailLog.Text = "";
      txtPasswordLog.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: i found this solution on a prior post on this web site and tried it like three days ago.

Comment: That will only update the values in ViewState which won't matter as the ViewState is not output again due to the redirect.